# Firebase Notifications - shows Invalid token when send notification on device test

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-notifications

```
**_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) async {    
      print(token);      
});**
```

this is my code how I get token using firebase, I add all dependencies correctly. But In firebase console, this token shows the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIOgK.png) invalid format

Comment: Please embed picture directly in the question.